# Shell script to to check if a line exist in a file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have tried all the solutions available on stack overflow, but when I use if condition with with it always results true.
I need to find a line in the file and see if it doesn't exit then insert the line in that file, but it always results that the line already exists.
Here is my script

```
isInFile=$(grep -q '^export' /etc/bashrc)
if [[ $isInFile == 0 ]];
then
    echo "line is not present";
    echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=\$?;logger -p local6.debug \"\$(whoami) [\$\$]: \$(history 1 | sed \"s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//\" )\"'" >> /etc/bashrc;
    source /etc/bashrc;
else
    echo "line is in the file";
fi
```

It always says that

```
line is in the file
```

Comment: you are probably looking for `if grep -q '^export' /etc/bashrc'`

Comment: The only way you will enter the first branch is if the `grep` outputs the literal text `0`.  Since you have passed `-q` to grep, that will never happen.  IsInFile is always the empty string.  This is one of those instances where `[` is much better than `[[`, since it gives you a useful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your code:

1. `if [[ $isInFile == 0 ]];` --If condition should not terminate with `;`. Remove that.
2. The expression you are checking is always an empty string. Try `echo $isInFile`. What you are checking is output of the command, not its return value. Instead, you should remove `-q` from your `grep` expression and check if the output is empty or not.

Following code should work:

```
isInFile=$(grep '^export' /etc/bashrc)
if [ -z "$isInFile" ]
then
    echo "line is not present";
    echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=\$?;logger -p local6.debug \"\$(whoami) [\$\$]: \$(history 1 | sed \"s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//\" )\"'" >> /etc/bashrc;
    source /etc/bashrc;
else
    echo "line is in the file";
fi
```

`-z` check for emptiness of variable.

Comment: There is no need to remove the `;`.  It is a bit unusual, but no different than having multiple newlines between the `if` and the `then`.  And it is quite common to write `if ...; then`.  Indeed, I would argue that the `;` should be retained, and the newline after the `;` should be discarded, but that's purely a stylistic choice.

Comment: Removing `-q` and checking that the output of `grep` is non-empty is an anti-pattern.  Instead of that, you should retain the `-q` and check the return status of `grep`, as shown in glenn jackman's answer.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell for the advice, I didn't know checking output of grep is considered `anti-pattern`. But it makes sense as this output can be huge and if we don't really need anything to do with output itself (and only check if it exists), there is no reason to load it in memory

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement branches based on *the **exit status** of the command it's given*. `[[` is just one command you can use, it's not mandatory syntax. At an interactive prompt, enter `help if`

Do this:

```sh
if grep -q '^export' /etc/bashrc
then
    # exit status of grep is zero: the pattern DOES MATCH the file
    echo "line is in the file";
else
    # exit status of grep is non-zero: the pattern DOES NOT MATCH the file
    echo "line is not present";
    echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=\$?;logger -p local6.debug \"\$(whoami) [\$\$]: \$(history 1 | sed \"s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//\" )\"'" >> /etc/bashrc;
    source /etc/bashrc;
fi
```